# How to hook into an angular component's events from a router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

So typically, when you target an event of a component it usually looks like this:

```
<some-component (someEventEmitter)="doSomething($event)"></some-component>
```

My question is, how would you pass in paramater info to the component if it's being rendered by the router-outlet?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't. If you want to get events from a component being rendered by the router, use some app wide service that you can use to subscribe and publish events through.

If you want to pass data into a component being rendered by the router, look at the queryParams and routeParams features that are part of the router.

Comment: So I can't subscribe to a component's events directly? What's the best practice here in this scenario?